# Convert Array of Array into string Array in efficient way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array

```
arr=[["Sumit", "where"], ["where", "are"], ["are", "you"]]
```

and i want to convert

```
arr=["Sumit where", "where are", "are you"]
```

how can i do this in efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
arr=[["Sumit", "where"], ["where", "are"], ["are", "you"]]
arr = arr.map {|i| i.join(' ') }
```

Comment: it gives ["Sumit", "where", "where", "are", "are", "you"] but i want to arr=["Sumit where", "where are", "are you]

Comment: is it possible without loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
arr=[["Sumit", "where"], ["where", "are"], ["are", "you"]]  
v = arr.map { |x| x.join(" ") }  
p v
```